# Three.js FBXLoader failed to load a big FBX model in three.js

Tags: three.js, fbx

When I load a large FBX model, which is 100MB in three.js, Chrome crashes, though it doesn't crash when I load a small FBX model. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Load less than 100MB?

100MB is an **extremely** large single asset for a page, three.js or otherwise. I highly recommend some optimization of your asset. Even if you get the contents into memory, three.js may not be able to render the contents.

Assuming everything in there is absolutely required, you could break the model into smaller chunks and load a whole bunch of assets. That might be possible. You also might have better luck with other 3d solutions (non-JS webpage) which could handle such a (still quite fat) asset.